How do I hide a question base on a answer of previous answer. Power Apps
Good day. Please help me.
I have many questions in my Power Apps form. Most with "Agree or disagree" options.
I want to add the function where if they select "Disagree" a new question opens to explain this choice they made in the previous question.
I also have a "varStep=2 or 1 or 3" option for each question under visible.


You will have to set Visible property of new/second question ("Disagree about the..." in above image) "data card" to something like this: varStep=2 && DataCardValue20.Selected.Value = "Disagree". Where, varStep=2 is your existing formula in "Visible" property AND DataCardValue20 is the name of drop down control under first question ("The OT Asset Inventory..." in above image). Try it and let me know if it works for you.
